# Iterating Array inside an Object and add property accordingly

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, recursion

So, I have a problem with recursion, this is the data:

```
let data = {
    label: "Root",
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "Parent 1"
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: "Child 1",
                    dataMax: 100,
                    datasets: 30
                },
                {
                    label: "Child 2",
                    dataMax: 30,
                    datasets: 30
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            label: "Parent 2",
            dataMax: 50,
            datasets: 30
        }
    ]
};
```

**What I wanted to do** was to iterate over this and put a property of let's say `dataMax` and data in every parent who doesn't have `dataMax`, and if the parent has two or more child, the `dataMax` will have the total values of it's childs.

Be noted, `data`'s depth and length is random.

Here's what I've tried:

```js
let data = {
    label: "Root",
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "Parent 1",
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: "Child 1",
                    dataMax: 100,
                    datasets: 30
                },
                {
                    label: "Child 2",
                    dataMax: 30,
                    datasets: 30
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            label: "Parent 2",
            dataMax: 50,
            datasets: 30
        }
    ]
};

let setDatas = function(x, i, p){
    if (x == undefined) {
        console.log("--- This is x==undefined ---");
        return 1;
    } else if (Array.isArray(x.datasets)) {
        console.log("-------------- " + x.label + ", datasets[" + [i] + "]:");
        console.log(x.datasets[i]);
        return setDatas(x.datasets[i], i, x);
    } else {
        console.log("It's not an Array");
        ++i;
        return setDatas(p, i, p);
    }
}

setDatas(data, 0);
```

I managed to get to the depth, but I can't seem to go to back to the Root, and I felt like I missed something but just can't seem to find it. Which did I do wrong?

**Desired Output:**

```
let data = {
    label: "Root",
    dataMax: 180, // Total from dataMax of Parent 1 and 2
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "Parent 1",
            dataMax: 130, // Total from dataMax of "Child 1" and dataMax of "Child 2"
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: "Child 1",
                    dataMax: 100,
                    datasets: 30
                },
                {
                    label: "Child 2",
                    dataMax: 30,
                    datasets: 30
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            label: "Parent 2",
            dataMax: 50,
            datasets: 30
        }
    ]
};
```

Thanks in advance. Feel free to ask for more info.

Comment: will you share what would be the desired output?

Comment: @diEcho updated, just adding extra info, I haven't tried to add the dataMax yet, because I was having trouble with getting back to the `Root`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your actual function you are not iterating over the `data.datasets`, you are just checking for the given `data`, you need to loop over the nested `data.datasets`.

You can use a combination of **[`Array#map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Map)** and **[`Array#reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)** methods like this:

```
function getDataMax(data) {
  if (data.datasets && Array.isArray(data.datasets)) {
    data.datasets = data.datasets.map(x => {
      if (!x.dataMax) {
        if (Array.isArray(x.datasets)) {
          //If inner datasets is an array do the recursive call
          getDataMax(x);
        }
      }
      return x;
    });
  }
  if (!data.dataMax)
    data.dataMax = data.datasets.map(x => x.dataMax).reduce((a, b) => (a + b));
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
let data = {
  label: "Root",
  datasets: [{
      label: "Parent 1",
      datasets: [{
          label: "Child 1",
          dataMax: 100,
          datasets: 30
        },
        {
          label: "Child 2",
          dataMax: 30,
          datasets: 30
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      label: "Parent 2",
      dataMax: 50,
      datasets: 30
    }
  ]
};


function getDataMax(data) {
  if (data.datasets && Array.isArray(data.datasets)) {
    data.datasets = data.datasets.map(x => {
      if (!x.dataMax) {
        if (Array.isArray(x.datasets)) {
          getDataMax(x);
        }
      }
      return x;
    });
  }
  if (!data.dataMax)
    data.dataMax = data.datasets.map(x => x.dataMax).reduce((a, b) => (a + b));
}
getDataMax(data);
console.log(data)
```

Comment: I tried your answer, however when I added a `dataset` on the Root, the dataMax of the root becomes `null`

Comment: @IrfandyJip My bad, I just missed to check the part where `data.datasets` isn't an array, I updated my answer and here's [your updated **working fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/chsdk/92htLvua/1/).

Comment: I tried adding depth, it resulted in NaN values to the one I add to. https://jsfiddle.net/irfandyjip89/139pwftc/11/

Comment: @IrfandyJip Sorry again, I just missed the whole recursion thing, I updated the answer and [**the fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/chsdk/wLmjfyer/1/).

Comment: Thanks! It works now, also thanks for the reference to `reduce` and `map`! Didn't knew such function exist.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works:

```
data = {
    label: "Root",
    datasets: [{
        label: "Parent 1",
        datasets: [{
            label: "Child 1",
            dataMax: 100,
            datasets: 30
        }, {
            label: "Child 2",
            dataMax: 30,
            datasets: 30
        }]
    }, {
        label: "Parent 2",
        dataMax: 50,
        datasets: 30
    }]
}

function setData(data) {
    if (Array.isArray(data.datasets)) {
        let childMax = 0;

        for (let i = 0; i < data.datasets.length; i++) {
            childMax += setData(data.datasets[i]);
        }

        if (data.dataMax === undefined) {
            data.dataMax = childMax;
        }
    }

    return data.dataMax;
}

setData(data);
```

Comment: Thanks! This does the job, and much easier to read. But what if I wanted to add another variable? For every parent they should also have an array of their child's data. Like in `Parent 1` will have a variable `data` consisting of `[30,30]`. Can this be done with this recursion too? Or it needs another logic?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method which also preserves original data

```js
    const datasets = [
            {
                label: "Parent 1",
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: "Child 1",
                        dataMax: 100,
                        datasets: 30
                    },
                    {
                        label: "Child 2",
                        dataMax: 30,
                        datasets: 30
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                label: "Parent 2",
                dataMax: 50,
                datasets: 30
            }
        ]; 
    
    
    const redfinedDataset = datasets.reduce( (prev, curr) => {
      if(curr.dataMax) { return prev.concat([curr]);}  
      else {
           if(curr.datasets.length >0) {
            const dataMax = curr.datasets.reduce( (pds, cds) => pds += cds.dataMax, 0);
            const nds = Object.assign(curr, {dataMax});
            return prev.concat([nds]);
           }
         }
    }, []);
    
    console.log(redfinedDataset);
```